# Releasing a view controller after a CATransition: Am I doing this right?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, catransition

My application is loading a first view (used to login into a Web service). When the login is successful, it performs a CATransition (basic kCATransitionFromRight) to show a second view and hides the first view. I've set the delegate of the transition to self so I can use `-(void)animationDidStop:(CATransition *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag`.

When that method is called (right after the transition is over) I want to release the first view since I won't need it anymore. However, when I call `[firstView release]` (in `animationDidStop:`) the retain count doesn't seem to change. I used `[loginView retainCount]` to check this and since I know it's not always reliable I was wondering: am I doing this right?

Thank you.

Comment: Every time somebody uses `retainCount`, God kills a kitten. It should really be avoided. As for your problem, are you removing the first view from its superview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Jilouc*** in his comment is right, forget to check "retaincount"...

if you want to be sure that your object view firstView just add a

```
NSLog(@"i'm removing myFirstView");
```

in its

```
-(void)dealloc{
}
```

method...

if you get that NSLog in debugger console window then be sure you had it removed/released in the right way...

btw... the right way could be something like this:

in animationDidStop:

```
if (firstView!=nil){
    [firstView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [firstView release];
    firstView=nil;
}
```

Comment: I added an NSLog into the dealloc method of my first view. I can see it's called when I set my animationDidStop method like you said but then the application is crashing, and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Maxime Bornemann: and where and when does it crash? if your dealloc method is called then the instance of your class is released and no more visible, and so its view and subViews and all objects created inside it... so, the crash may happens if after that you try to "call" it (or a property of it) again. for example: if you call [firstView.view.center]; ... try to catch where your app crashes...

Comment: You're right. Some old piece of code was trying to manipulate the view after the transition. Everything is working fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

taken from the book "Cocoa Touch for iPhone OS 3" is a similar approach.
They set up an animation remove the old subview, add the new one and then commit the animation.